# How do I Return SUM from JPA Query Using Hibernate and Spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpql

I am trying to use JPA and JPQL to query my entity and return the sum of a column (total days) from the table.  I thought I had set it up right but I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'myRepository':
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method
public abstract java.lang.Float
com.nissan.rca.repository.MyRepository.selectTotals()!
```

Here is a representation of my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLENAME")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyEntityCompositeKey myEntityCompositeKey;

    @Column(name = "raiser_id")
    private String raiserID;

    @Column(name = "total_days")
    private Float totalDays;
```

and here is my repository in which I make the query assigned to a method:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, ID> {
    @Query("SELECT SUM(total_days) FROM MyEntity")
    Float selectTotals();
}
```

I call the selectTotals() method from myRepository object in my rest controller for the api mapping.

```
@GetMapping("/getForecastTotals")
public Float getForecastTotals() {
    return myRepository.selectTotals();
}
```

I'm unsure as to why it can't be returned as a float.

Comment: In your query you are using the column name, use the attribute name (totalDays) and this should work fine.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's not a valid JPQL.

You either should have:

`@Query("SELECT SUM(m.totalDays) FROM MyEntity m")`

or, make it a native one:

`@Query(value = "SELECT SUM(total_days) FROM MyEntity", nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: if you make a native one, be sure to use IF NULL. Ex: @Query(value = "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(total_days), 0) FROM MyEntity", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: @KenobiBastila For JPQL you can use COALESCE instead of IF NULL. Ex: @Query(value = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(e.total_days), 0) FROM MyEntity e")

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this by mapping a new POJO

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, ID> {
    @Query("SELECT new com.NewPojo(SUM(m.totalDays)) FROM MyEntity m")
    NewPojo selectTotals();
}

class NewPojo {
    Float days;
    public NewPojo(Float days) {
        this.days = days;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I was looking for a solution in sum for my DTO, this solution helped me. `new com.myDTO(recipientName, SUM(p.price))...`

Answer (score 0):

change your JPQL to `@Query("SELECT SUM(m.totalDays) FROM MyEntity m")`