# How to sum the cost of each item in a One To Many relationship JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

How could I calculate the total of an order in a one to many relationship, when the customer buys a certain number of items in the order attribute, he wants to know, he could start to investigate, to carry out that. I'm really a little confused, I really want to learn

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
class Order(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Int? = 0,

  
        val name: String? = "",
        val address: String? = "",
        val phone: String? = "",
        
        val totalOrderPrice: Long? // total based on the cost of each item


        @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.MERGE])
        @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
        val items: List<Items>? = mutableListOf()
)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
class Items(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long? = null,
        val name: String? = null,

        val price: Long?, // cost item

    )
```

Comment: Check if this is your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637103/how-do-i-return-sum-from-jpa-query-using-hibernate-and-spring-boot/51637609).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to correct your mapping. In child entity, you should have parent entity's reference. Which mean in "Items" class add reference to Order id as column "orderId". Then your class should look like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
class Items(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long? = null,
        val orderId: int? = null,
        val name: String? = null,

        val price: Long?, // cost item
    )
```

Now, You have 3 options here to calculate the total price of order

1. Write JPA query like this

   **@Query("SELECT SUM(m.price) FROM Items m where orderId = :orderId")**

   **Long getOrderPrice(@Param("orderId") Long orderId);**
2. Write Native SQL query like this

   **@Query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM items where order_id = :orderId", nativeQuery = true)**

   **Long getOrderPrice(@Param("orderId") Long orderId);**
3. In Java using streams or for loop, calculate the total price

   **Long sum = order.getItems.map(i->i.getprice()).stream().reduce(Long::sum).get();**

Comment: I really appreciate your help! You are amazing

Comment: Good to know, it helped you