# Get SUM instead of COUNT without native Query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA with MySQL database. I have following database table:

```
id   points   user_id
1    35       1
2    40       1
3    25       1
4    2500     2
```

And I want to get the `SUM()` of the column `points`, but not with native Query.

In Repository I can use the Method to `COUNT()` the lines. When I try `sum` instead of count I get an error.

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    
    public Long countPointsByUser(User user); // for user #1 returns 3
    public Long sumPointsByUser(User user); // throws an exception, but I want return of 100 for user #1 and 2500 for user #2

}
```

Is it possible with Spring Data JPA to write a Method in Interface without `@Query` annotation?

Comment: It is not possible, you can read the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories). And it's easy to write JPQL with @Query annotation

Comment: You can look here for JPQL solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637103/how-do-i-return-sum-from-jpa-query-using-hibernate-and-spring-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. In my case it fits.

I create a view with `SUM(points)`, create an Entity for the View, a Repository for the new Entity and just call `findAll()`.

Thanks for help. This explained why dont find anything in documentation.