# How do i perform arithmetic operation on elements of list in Java?

Tags: java, list, jpa

An entity named Transaction have two type of transactions '*credit*' and '*debit*'. Objects of entity are *date* , *id*(used sequence generator), **amount** and a *foreign key*.

What I have done is that I crated two Typedqueries to select transaction by transaction types(credit or debit) and store the Typedqueries result in two List.

I want to return the difference of total amount from credit transactions to total amount from debit type transactions(**summation of all credit transaction - summation of all debit transactions**). It will give me balance.

My code:

```
public Result getBalanceByTransaction(Http.Request request,String userName)
    {
        Account a; Wallet w;
        a = jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {
            return entityManager.createNamedQuery("detailsByName",Account.class).setParameter("name",userName).getSingleResult();
        }); long account_id = a.getId();
        w = jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {
           return entityManager.createNamedQuery("walletById",Wallet.class).setParameter("id",account_id).getSingleResult();
        });

        String queryForCredit ="select transaction.amount from Transaction transaction where transaction.txnType ='CREDIT' and transaction.wallet.id =:id";
        String queryForDebit = "select transaction.amount from Transaction transaction where transaction.txnType ='DEBIT' and transaction.wallet.id =:id";
        TypedQuery <Transaction> allCredit = jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {
           return entityManager.createQuery(queryForCredit,Transaction.class);
        });
        List <Transaction> allCreditTxn = allCredit.getResultList();
        TypedQuery <Transaction> allDebit = jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {
           return entityManager.createQuery(queryForDebit,Transaction.class);
        });
        List <Transaction> allDebitTxn = allDebit.getResultList();


    }
```

How do i perform arithmetic operation on **'amount'** object of multiple entities stored in List.

Comment: what's exactly your problem? Doing for loop and summing up the amount? Or something else? It isn't clear from your description

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for total amounts you should perform the summation within the JPL query, to avoid querying the whole `Transaction` entity. You can do this with `SUM()` operator, as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51637609/1602555):

```sql
SELECT SUM(t.amount) 
FROM Transaction t
WHERE t.txnType ='CREDIT'
AND t.wallet.id =:id
```

If you are attempting to calculate the account balance you might want to change your database model to store this value somewhere e.g. `Wallter.balance` field. Calculating this every single time balance is displayed feels wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you can compute the sum within your query already but if you want to sum it up in a `List`, you can do that in a functional way by using `map` and `reduce()` and [method references](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-references#:%7E:text=Method%20references%20are%20a%20special,Instance%20methods%20of%20particular%20objects).

```java
List<Transaction> credit = Arrays.asList(new Transaction(100d), new Transaction(100d), new Transaction(100d), new Transaction(100d));
List<Transaction> debit = Arrays.asList(new Transaction(100d), new Transaction(250d));

// sum up all amount for credit and debit
var totalCredit = credit.stream().map(Transaction::getAmount).reduce(0d, Double::sum);
var totalDebit = debit.stream().map(Transaction::getAmount).reduce(0d, Double::sum);

// print result
System.out.println(totalCredit - totalDebit);
```

Expected output:

```
50.0
```

`Transaction.java`

```java
public class Transaction {
    private double amount;

    public Transaction(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

If your `Transaction` uses another datatype than `double`, note that `sum` does also exist for those other datatype e.g. `Integer:sum`.