# How to use @Query in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

I'm trying to access expense where type is income through spring(2.7.6) jpa using @Query annotation.[screenshot of database postgresql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOzEh.png)

Error in terminal:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'expenseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'expenseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'expenseRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expenseRepository' defined in com.ivy.expensely.repository.ExpenseRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional com.ivy.expensely.repository.ExpenseRepository.findByType(java.lang.String); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.ivy.expensely.repository.ExpenseRepository.findByType(java.lang.String)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.ivy.expensely.repository.ExpenseRepository.findByType(java.lang.String)!
```

I'm trying to execute in ExpenseRepository;

```
import com.ivy.expensely.model.Expense;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends JpaRepository<Expense,Long> {

//    @Query(value = "select sum(amount) from expense where type:income",nativeQuery = true)
@Query("SELECT sum(amount) FROM expense WHERE type='income'")
    public Optional<Expense> findByType(String param_name);
}
```

Model looks like this:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="expense")
public class Expense {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Instant expensedate;

    private String description;

    private String location;

    private Long amount;

    private String type;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
```

Please help me in figuring out how to execute this

Answer (score 0):

Sum returns Long (as it a sum of amounts, which is Long), so try this:

```
@Query("SELECT sum(e.amount) FROM expense e WHERE e.type='income'")
public Long findByType(String param_name);
```

In JPQL Queries you have to specify the table of the where clause fields. Also remember to set the correct return type for the repository method. More info at [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query). Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637103/how-do-i-return-sum-from-jpa-query-using-hibernate-and-spring-boot).